# Case statement not working with numeric values in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

My requirement is to write a case statement, something like mentioned below. But I am not getting the correct data.

```
SELECT DIRECCION
        ,CASE WHEN DIRECCION  like'%PISO [^0-9]%' THEN 'PISO [0-9]'
         ELSE 'PISO 1' END
  FROM TBL_SAR_SALAS
```

I think my attempt to find the numeric characters is not working ...moreover ISNUMERIC is also not supported.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want us to guess from a query that DOESN'T do what you want it to do? Does that make any sense to you? Please provide a small sample of data, the logic of your requirement, and what the output should be based on your small sample of data and on the requirement. And do NOT include any code in any of that! THEN you can say "here is what I tried, what it does, and what it doesn't do right."

Comment: `[^0-9`]` has no meaning with the LIKE operator, it stands for that literal sequence of characters. In a regular expression, it stands for any single character OTHER THAN a digit. I assume neither is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for that..I just want to select  value (PISO [ANY NUMERIC CHARACTER]) from a varchar column of dynamic length.

Comment: So, `PISO 123 NEW` becomes `PISO 123`, `PISO 123A` becomes `PISO 123`, `PISO A123` becomes `PISO 1`, `MANHATTAN` becomes `PISO 1`, and `null` becomes `PISO 1`? If not, please be more precise!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if it's any `PISO` with a space then a number... or what, so we'd have to work on the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but this gives you the general idea.

But `regexp_Like` seems to be the function you're after...

```
WITH cte as (Select 'PISO 123' as Direccion from dual union all
             SELECT 'PISO123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT '123 PISO' FROM DUAL)

SELECT direccion
     , Case when REGEXP_LIKE(Direccion ,'PISO[^0-9]') then 'PISO [0-9]' else 'PISO 1' end
FROM cte
```

Comment: My guess is different, I believe he meant ^ as an anchor at the beginning of the "word" (so that PISO 123 and PISO 123A would both work) - but WHY DO WE HAVE TO GUESS? Is there a big money prize for guessing right?   {:-)

Comment: My point was to convey the existence of the function `REGEXP_LIKE` not the actual regular expression.

Comment: And my point wasn't to disagree with your interpretation or with demonstrating the `regexp_like()` function, but to simply point out that we shouldn't have to guess! The more some of us do, the more posters think it's OK...

Comment: It is partially correct.. the output which I am getting here is :"PISO [0-9]" where the value (PISO  NUMERIC character is found) and else condition is absolutely correct.

Comment: But I want the exact numeric  value  i.e after the word "PISO"  For e.g "CALLE SANTA MARIA  110  PISO 3 INT. 301 MIRAFLORES" .For this input ..output should be PISO 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Note the second example; by default, Oracle is case sensitive in strings. Also note the use of `coalesce()`: if the desired substring is not found - that is, if `regexp_substr()` returns `null` -  then the result is `'PISO 1'`. If you want the query to disregard capitalization, that can be adjusted easily (with an argument to `regexp_substr()`).

```
with
     tbl_sar_salas ( direccion ) as (
       select 'ALPHA PISO 123 NORTH' from dual union all
       select 'piso 123'             from dual union all
       select 'PISO 123ABC'          from dual union all
       select null                   from dual union all
       select 'MANHATTAN'            from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select direccion,
       coalesce (regexp_substr(direccion, 'PISO [0-9]+'), 'PISO 1') as result
from tbl_sar_salas
;


DIRECCION              RESULT             
--------------------   --------------------
ALPHA PISO 123 NORTH   PISO 123            
piso 123               PISO 1              
PISO 123ABC            PISO 123            
                       PISO 1              
MANHATTAN              PISO 1
```